# How to make thread wait for a certain event to occur

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Could you help me, please?

What I'm trying to do is a printer example. There will be more printers and more documents waiting to be printed.

A `Printer` is a `Thread`, it sleeps until a document is arrived, then prints it, then goes to sleep again.

A `PrinterManager` is a thread too. It collects documents from a queue and sends to a free `Printer`. I am using a `Semaphore` for finding a free printer.

The problem is around the wait-notify pair. The printer should wait until the manager sends a document. Then it waits 1 second and "prints" it. As a lock object I use `stick`.

For some reason, it's not working. The document is sent succesfully to the printer, but the printer is not awaken. Can you help me, why?

Printer thread:

```
public class Printer extends Thread {

    private final Semaphore semaphore;
    private final Object stick;
    private String document;

    public Printer(Semaphore semaphore, Object stick) {
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
        this.stick = stick;
    }

    public void setDocument(String document) {
        this.document = document;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                stick.wait();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Printing: " + document);
                semaphore.release();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Manager thread:

```
public class PrinterManager extends Thread {

    private final Printer[] printers = new Printer[1];
    private final Object stick = new Object();
    private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(printers.length);
    private final DocumentQueue queue;

    public PrinterManager(DocumentQueue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
        printers[0] = new Printer(semaphore, stick);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                semaphore.acquire();
                String toPrint = takeNextDocument();
                printers[0].setDocument(toPrint);
                synchronized (stick) {
                    stick.notify();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private String takeNextDocument() throws InterruptedException {
        return queue.take();
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you be notifying the printer, not the stick?

Comment: No, that would cause `IllegalMonitorStateException`

Comment: If I recall correctly you need to synchronize the `wait()` call on `stick`, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder how many times of 1000 runs the printer will print the document (will you conduct an experiment?).

But first put `stick.wait()` in Printer's run method in synchronized block, or you'll be getting IllegalMonitorStateException exception in there.

You've faced concurrency problems called race condition and deadlock. It means the result depends on order in which code is executed. Sometimes you might be lucky and the program would work as you expect. But in other times you're going to have a deadlock (that's another concurrency programming issue).

Imagine instructions are executed in that sequence:

1. `PrinterManager.run()` acquires semaphore
2. `PrinterManager.run()` sets document to the printer
3. `PrinterManager.run()` executes notify on stick
4. `Printer.run()` executes `stick.wait()`

...and this is how you get a deadlock.
`PrinterManager` notified the `stick` before `Printer` started to wait on it. Then `PrinterManager` acquired the last permit in semaphore and started to wait until `Printer` release some (it never will, it waits!). Both objects started to wait for each other and both got blocked.

But `Printer` could started to wait before `PrinterManager` notified objects on stick, than it would work as expected. That's why you have race condition, you can never predict what will happen and this is very bad.

As a simple solution (not the best, but quick and without help of additional techniques which you may find unfamiliar) you may get rid of stick. Introduce two counters instead:

`numberOfFinishedPrintTasks` (make `Printer` increment it after each turn)

and `lastSubmittedPrintTaskNumber` (make `PrinterManager` set it to `numberOfFinishedPrintTasks + 1` after each submission).

`PrinterManager` must check the condition `numberOfFinishedPrintTasks == lastSubmittedPrintTaskNumber` it means that printer finished all work and new tasks can be submitted.

P.S. Don't inherit for `Thread` class. You don't add any new functionality to `Thread`, you just make it run a specific job. 
For that you should create an object which implements `Runnable` interface and pass that object to new `Thread` instance.